# How to add RGB or CMYK output intent profile to a PDF

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, pdfa, asciidoctor-pdf

With `asciidoctor-pdf -a optimize=PDF/A-1 mytext.adoc` which is a simple testfile

```
:author: Maxim Kim
:subject: pdfa Test
:keywords: Keyw1, Keyw2
:doctype: article

some text
```

Now a PDF is created without errors or warnings, but if fails the PDF\A check with veraPDF. Now depending on which standard I try to build and to check the validation error is slightly different, but the suberror is always the same:

```
DeviceRGB colour space is used without RGB output intent profile
```

Sometimes veraPDF also says that RGB or CMYK should be used, but not both. So my question now: How can I include one of those intent profiles into the PDF. Unfortunately the search on PDF\A with asciidoctor-pdf has little information.

Edit: After a lot of searching I found  [this comment](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/125#issuecomment-1116850083) . So apparently `asciidoc-pdf` shouldn't be used to create pdf with PDF\A standard.